# Find line (one only) based on first string in line using C++

Tags: c++

**Objective:** 
Find the correct line in the datafile to make adjustment on by searching for email address

**Problem:** 
I can find the line when I use `string::find` as per the current code below, but when I search for `rick@fakedomain.tld` I get two hits, the `frederick@` and `rick@` lines. As the email address is first field I cant include a leading space (delimiter) to overcome the problem.

**Sample input datafile (called datafile):**

```
alan@fakedomain.tld q7gPGAdb0zGKHlQd./ Alan Smith
frederick@fakedomain.tld cyHSYctfJpOq7gPGAd Frederick Smith
david@fakedomain.tld nz0hz1uevogQgNxqQA David Smith
rick@fakedomain.tld 4bExd5J3tU7Pi9o/My Rick Smith
john@fakedomain.tld q7gPGAdb0zGKHlQd./0 John Smith
```

**Current c++ code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // Are there the right number of command line arguments
    if (argc < 2) { // expecting 2, the command and email address
        cout << "test [emailaddress]" << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    if (argc > 2) {
        cout << "test: to many arguments" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    // put the command line arguments into string variables
    string cmd = argv[0];
    string email = argv[1];

    // display the command line for testing - remove secton for production
    string space = " ";
    string cmdline = cmd + space + email + space + oldPW + space + oldPW;
    cout << cmdline << endl;

    // Open the files
    ifstream filein("datafile"); //File to read from
    if(!filein)
    {
        cout << "Error opening file!" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    string strLine;
    while(getline(filein, strLine))
    {
        // the test to see if this is the line to work with
        size_t found = strLine.find(email);
        if (found != string::npos) {
            // this is the string so add code here to work with it
            cout << strLine << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Question:**
How do I only return the line with an exact match of the needle?

If it's not asking to much, hoping for an answer that teaches me, not just some un-commented code that works, but will take the latter if it’s all I can get.

Optional: if there is a better way to do other parts of the code you see, feel free to suggest in your answer or comment. Always keen to learn better ways.

**Desired output**

```
./test rick@fakedomain.tld
alan@fakedomain.tld q7gPGAdb0zGKHlQd./ Alan Smith
 - - no match
frederick@fakedomain.tld cyHSYctfJpOq7gPGAd Frederick Smith    
 - - no match
david@fakedomain.tld nz0hz1uevogQgNxqQA David Smith
 - - no match
rick@fakedomain.tld 4bExd5J3tU7Pi9o/My Rick Smith
 |=|=| MATCH
john@fakedomain.tld q7gPGAdb0zGKHlQd./0 John Smith
 - - no match
```

**Output I'm getting**

```
./test rick@fakedomain.tld
alan@fakedomain.tld q7gPGAdb0zGKHlQd./ Alan Smith
 - - no match
frederick@fakedomain.tld cyHSYctfJpOq7gPGAd Frederick Smith    
 |=|=| MATCH
david@fakedomain.tld nz0hz1uevogQgNxqQA David Smith
 - - no match
rick@fakedomain.tld 4bExd5J3tU7Pi9o/My Rick Smith
 |=|=| MATCH
john@fakedomain.tld q7gPGAdb0zGKHlQd./0 John Smith
 - - no match
```

NB: No compile errors or warnings using `g++ test.c -o test`

Comment: You require found==0, i.e. beginning of line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make sure the the found email is at the start of the string then just check to make sure found is zero.

```
if (found == 0)
    cout << strLine << endl;
```

Another option is to use [`std::string::substr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_cmp) on the line from the file and do a direct comparison with [`operator ==`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_cmp)

```
if (email == strLine.substr(0, email.size()))
    cout << strLine << endl;
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked. I used the second one (`std::string::substr`) as it's something that looks like it can be used where ever it is in the line which is a bit more useful, but also noted the first.